# Fill a list of 2 lists from split string

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This might be too trivial of a question for Code Review, but here goes:

Assume I have text file with content:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

And I want a list like `[[1,2,3,4],["A","B","C","D"]]` created by Python's list comprehensions.

My code accomplishes this, but it seems like I jump through way too many loops:

```
with open('textFile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

z = [y for y in map(list, list(zip(*[x.split() for x in lines])))]
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this using list comprehension?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While the code to review is pretty minimal, I still think it is reviewable to an extent. I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're going to use `map`, then it's simpler to surround it in a `list()` call, then a list comprehension.
- Rather than using `list(map(list, it))`, you can instead use a list comprehension.

  ```
  [list(i) for i in it]
  ```
- You don't need to use `list(zip())`, it only hinders performance and readability.
- You don't have to use a list comprehension with `*`, instead you could use a generator comprehension.
- You don't have to use `f.readlines()`, if you perform the comprehension in the `with`.

Merging this all together gets:

```
with open('textFile.txt') as f:
    z = [list(i) for i in zip(*(j.split() for j in f))]
```